# Slipstreaming 64 bit XP CD on a 32 bit machine

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit

I have a Windows XP 64 bit install CD with no service packs. I would like to update it to Service Pack 2 (to reinstall a broken 64 bit machine). I only have access to a machine running 32 bit Windows XP. When I run:

> WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB914961-SP2-x64-ENU.exe /integrate:C:\XP\

on my 32-bit Windows XP machine, I get the following error:

> amd64\update\update.exe is not a valid
>   Win32 application.

Is there any workaround to create a 64-bit XP slipstream CD on a 32-bit XP OS?

Comment: Find someone with an MSDN subscription, who can download the XP ISO for you. They won't be in breach of their agreement if they don't give you an activation key.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.nliteos.com/index.html it allows for slipstreaming service packs, drivers, removing unwanted parts of OS and even creating automated instalations.

Comment: This is bogus. On a 32-bit platform, Nlite only says, "Slipstreaming 64-bit Service Packs is supported only from 64 bit OS."